# Parallelogram with one side tangent to circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, plane-geometry

> As shown in the figure, $ABCD$ is a parallelogram. $DE=3$, $DC=2$, find $BE$.
>
> [image: Figure]

Below is what I have:
$$AB=CD=2$$
$$AB^2=BE\times BC \implies 4=BE\times BC$$
$$AD\parallel BC \implies AE=CD=2$$
$$\angle ABE = \angle AEB = \angle ADC$$

That's all I found. How should I move on?

Comment: can you show that $\triangle ABE$ is similar to $\triangle DAE$? In which case the result will follow easily.

Comment: @DavidQuinn Indeed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Draw AE and let the intersection of extended AB and DE be K. As $BK\parallel CD, \triangle DEC \sim \triangle EBK$. As $\frac{DC}{DE}=\frac{2}{3}$, You can label $EK=3x$ and $BK=2x$

As you found that $AE=CD$ I am not going to prove it again.

Also, you can see that $\triangle AEK \sim \triangle ADK$. By similarity, you can find the following relationship.

$\frac{2+2x}{3+3x}=\frac{3x}{2+2x}$

By simplifying

$(2+2x)^2=3x(3+3x)$

$x=\frac{4}{5}$         [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5B%5C%2840%292%2B2x%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%3D3x%5C%2840%293%2B3x%5C%2841%29)

Again by the similarity of $\triangle AEK \sim \triangle DAK$ you get,

$\frac{2}{AD}=\frac{2+2x}{3+3x}$

Substituting the value for x you get,

$AD=3$    [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5B2%2Cx%5D%3DDivide%5B2%2BDivide%5B8%2C5%5D%2C3%2BDivide%5B12%2C5%5D%5D)

As $BE \parallel AD, \triangle EBK \sim \triangle ADK$ you get the following relationships,

$\frac{BE}{AD}=\frac{2x}{2+2x}$

By substituting values for $AD$ and $x$

$\boxed{BE=\frac{4}{3}}$  [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5Bb%2C3%5D%3DDivide%5BDivide%5B8%2C5%5D%2C2%2BDivide%5B8%2C5%5D%5D)